# how to highlight elisp macro argument?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

when I use "use-package" macro in emacs lisp, I found that the argument is highlighted.
[image: macro argument is highlighted]

but argument of my own macro is not highlighted by emacs.

[image: mine not highlighted]

How to write a macro with highlighted arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use-package` uses `font-lock-add-keywords` to mark the argument with `font-lock-constant-face`.  Replacing "use-package" with "test_macro" in the the code would colorize your argument similarly

```
(defconst my-font-lock-keywords
  '(("(\\(test_macro\\)\\_>[ \t']*\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)?"
     (1 font-lock-keyword-face)
     (2 font-lock-constant-face nil t))))

(font-lock-add-keywords 'emacs-lisp-mode my-font-lock-keywords)
```